# How to add four three icons on Action bar in Android

Tags: android

I want to add three or more than three icons on Action bar, I have tried but my third icons does not on the action bar .Can someone explain me how to add third option on action bar .How to resolve this issue.

**menu.xml**

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:appcompat="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:title="@string/action_settings"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/imgAdd"
        android:title="@string/CreatePost"
        android:orderInCategory="200"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_add"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom"></item>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_search"
        android:title="menu_search"
        android:orderInCategory="300"
        appcompat:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
        appcompat:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>

</menu>
```

**acivity code**

```
public class AllPost_ActionBar extends ActionBarActivity
{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.all_post);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        // Inflate menu to add items to action bar if it is present.
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
        SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.menu_search).getActionView();
        searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:title="@string/action_settings"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        app:showAsAction="always"/>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/imgAdd"
        android:title="@string/CreatePost"
        android:orderInCategory="200"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_add"
        app:showAsAction="always"></item>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_search"
        android:title="menu_search"
        android:orderInCategory="300"
        appcompat:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
        app:showAsAction="always"/>

</menu>
```

Comment: Still not display three icon only two icons are showing .This itme = <item
        android:id="@+id/imgAdd"
        android:title="@string/CreatePost"
        android:orderInCategory="200"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_add"
        app:showAsAction="always"></item> this item not showing

Comment: It depends on device width. Please review [official document](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/actionbar.html) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

With your menu.xml file. You need change **app:showAsAction="ifRoom"** to  **appcompat:showAsAction="always"** if you want icon show. With menu item settings, you can use **app:showAsAction="never"** or **appcompat:showAsAction="never"**.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:appcompat="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:orderInCategory="300"
        android:title="@string/action_settings"
        appcompat:showAsAction="never"/>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/imgAdd"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_add"
        android:orderInCategory="200"
        android:title="@string/CreatePost"
        appcompat:showAsAction="always"></item>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_search"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:title="menu_search"
        appcompat:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
        appcompat:showAsAction="always"/>

</menu>
```

The menu items are arranged from left to right in ascending order of integer value of `android:orderInCategory` (i.e. 100,200,300... -> left to right).

Comment: i use your code line but getting error of Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Users\Seachange\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\build-tools\21.1.1\aapt.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

Comment: At first you go to "Build"-> "Clean Project"

and then go to "Build" -> "Rebuild Project"

Comment: Still getting same error . Can any change iin gradle file

Comment: hmm, this is my gradle : 
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
}

Comment: This is my gradle file  dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
    compile 'com.nostra13.universalimageloader:universal-image-loader:1.9.4'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:21.0.+'  dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
    compile 'com.nostra13.universalimageloader:universal-image-loader:1.9.4'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:21.0.+'

Comment: or you can try a search with keyword "aapt.exe finished with non-zero exit value 1 android studio".

Comment: Yes i surfing on net , and build and clean only

Comment: Try restart Android Studio. Maybe it works :). I have checked my code It run ok on my device

Comment: I have restart also but same error come again and again

Comment: Hello, maybe you have double :
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
in your xml.
Check your xml again.